# Add key/value metas to sql query as columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I made an SQL query which is returning the content and the metas as columns

```
SELECT 
    content.content_id AS id,
    content.content_title AS author,
    content.content_body AS review,
    content.content_date as date,
    m0.meta_value AS email,
    m1.meta_value AS origin,
    m2.meta_value AS recommend,
    m3.meta_value AS avatar
FROM
    molly_contents content,
    molly_content_meta m0,
    molly_content_meta m1,
    molly_content_meta m2,
    molly_content_meta m3
WHERE
    content.content_type = 'review'
        AND content.content_id = m0.meta_content_id
        AND m0.meta_name = 'email'
        AND content.content_id = m1.meta_content_id
        AND m1.meta_name = 'origin'
        AND content.content_id = m2.meta_content_id
        AND m2.meta_name = 'recommendation'
        AND content.content_id = m3.meta_content_id
        AND m3.meta_name = 'avatar'
ORDER BY
    content.content_date DESC
```

The problem is, if there is a missing meta it wont return that record. 
Is there any solution to return each record as a single row with the meta names as column names, and if there is no meta name then leave it empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is simpler as conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT c.*,
       MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_name = 'email' THEN m.metavalue END) as email,
       MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_name = 'origin' THEN m.metavalue END) as email,
       MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_name = 'recommendation' THEN m.metavalue END) as recommendation,
       MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_name = 'avatar' THEN m.metavalue END) as avatar
FROM molly_contents c left join
     molly_content_meta m
     ON c.content_id = m.meta_content_id
GROUP BY c.content_id;
```

The fundamental flaw with your query is that you are using commas in the from clause.  Here is a simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause; always use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Then, you would be able to change your joins to `LEFT JOIN`, which is another way of solving your problem.

Comment: Thank you, this is what i needed.